# How to get data multi symbol multi timeframes?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have 14 symbols and 7 timeframes, how do I get the open close high low of candle 3, candle 2, candle 1, candle 0 of each symbol of each timeframes.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Multiple Time Frame OHLC", overlay=true)

// Input symbols
symbol1 = input("XAUUSD", title="Symbol 1")
symbol2 = input("GBPUSD", title="Symbol 2")
symbol3 = input("GBPAUD", title="Symbol 3")
symbol4 = input("AUDJPY", title="Symbol 4")
symbol5 = input("GBPJPY", title="Symbol 5")
symbol6 = input("GBPCAD", title="Symbol 6")
symbol7 = input("GBPCHF", title="Symbol 7")
symbol8 = input("EURUSD", title="Symbol 8")
symbol9 = input("AUDUSD", title="Symbol 9")
symbol10 = input("USDCAD", title="Symbol 10")
symbol11 = input("CHFJPY", title="Symbol 11")
symbol12 = input("USDJPY", title="Symbol 12")
symbol13 = input("EURJPY", title="Symbol 13")

// Create table
table = table.new(position.top_right, 8, 14)

table.cell(table, 0, 0, "SYMBOL", text_color=color.white)
table.cell(table, 1, 0, "D1", text_color=color.white)
table.cell(table, 2, 0, "H4", text_color=color.white)
table.cell(table, 3, 0, "H3", text_color=color.white)
table.cell(table, 4, 0, "H2", text_color=color.white)
table.cell(table, 5, 0, "H1", text_color=color.white)
table.cell(table, 6, 0, "M30", text_color=color.white)
table.cell(table, 7, 0, "M15", text_color=color.white)


// lấy all data của all tf của symbol1
ohlc_d1_array_symbol1 = request.security(symbol1, "D",array.from(open, high, low, close, open[1],high[1], low[1], close[1], open[2],high[2], low[2], close[2],open[3], high[3], low[3], close[3], ta.sma(close, 20)))


// Trích xuất OHLC 3,2,1,0, price, sma20 của các nến D1
d1_open_3_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 12)
d1_high_3_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 13)
d1_low_3_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 14)
d1_close_3_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 15)

d1_open_2_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 8)
d1_high_2_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 9)
d1_low_2_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 10)
d1_close_2_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 11)

d1_open_1_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 4)
d1_high_1_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 5)
d1_low_1_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 6)
d1_close_1_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 7)

d1_open_0_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 0)
d1_high_0_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 1)
d1_low_0_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 2)
d1_close_0_symbol1 = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 3)

price1D = array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 3)
sma20_1D =array.get(ohlc_d1_array_symbol1, 16)
```

With 1 symbol and 1 timeframes, I use 1 request to get all the necessary information.But when I finished 1 symbol with a full time frame, the code ran very slowly and study error: error on bar0: cannlot call array methods when id of array is na

Is there any way to solve the problem get the open close high low of candle 3, candle 2, candle 1, candle 0 of each symbol of each timeframes.